# Is stereo audio two times shorter than mono?

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing

I can't find answer, question as above.

I have two files with sound data, with the same **amount of bytes**, the same **sample size** and the same **sample rate**. One is in **mono**, another is in **stereo**. Is stereo audio two times shorter than mono audio? Should I consider sample rate as sample per channel rate or literally sample rate (no distinction between channels)?

I'm working on app which will split channels from multichannel audio. Should I reduce framerate of splitted tracks by half?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

filesize = sample size * channels * sample rate * time

or reformed:

time = filesize / (sample size * channels * sample rate)

So: **YES** the stereo file (channels == 2) will be half as long [measuring time here] if everything else is constant.